# C++ Overloading addition operator to add objects

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm working on a project where I need to add two objects together by overloading the addition operator, 99% of it makes sense to me, but I can't figure out how to do the actual addition process.

My code is currently

```
Time operator+(const Time& t1)
{
     int num = this.milliseconds + t1.milliseconds;
     Time t(num);
     return t;
}
```

Then I call it like so

```
t4 = t1 + t2;
```

I thought using `this.milliseconds` would allow me to access `t1`'s int variable but it won't allow me.

Basically my question is how do I access the time variable on the left of the + operator since I only pass the operator+ function one object of Time? (t2)

Comment: `this` is a pointer

Comment: The code you show should work if you just remove `this.`, if it is part of the `Time` class. You should make that member function `const`, or better, make it a free function of two arguments using the class' `operator+=`.

Comment: Also, instead of defining a local variable and returning that, just construct a `Time` instance directly in the `return` statement, e.g. `return {num};`.

Comment: Also, as part of conditioning yourself to use good programming practices as a matter of course, make that `num` a `const` variable.

Answer (score 2):

If your `operator+` is a member function of the `Time` class then you should be able to access its fields when you change `this.milliseconds` to `this->milliseconds` or just `milliseconds`. Please note that `this` is a pointer so it requires the `->` operator.

You don't have to be concerned about the `operator+` having only one parameter. If you overload a two argument operator as a class member then it is implicitly assumed that the first argument of the operator is `this`.

You have also a possibility to overload an operator as a non-member function and then you have to specify two parameters like this: `Time operator+(const Time& t1, const Time& t2)`.

It is also worth mentioning that your `operator+` could be a `const` member function.